# Intellij Idea 12 IDE talk connect to ejabberd

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, ejabberd

Has anyone had any problems connecting Intellij Idea's IDE talk to the ejabberd? When I try to do so, I get "Error: No response from the server." error message. I use "Use existing account" option.

ejabberd log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2014-01-28 10:05:08 ===
I(<0.456.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.437>) Accepted connection {{10,67,254,75},51851} -> {{10,67,254,101},5222}

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-01-28 10:05:09 ===
I(<0.477.0>:ejabberd_c2s:631) : ({socket_state,tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.437>,#Port<0.439>},<0.476.0>}) Accepted authentication for xxxxx by ejabberd_auth_internal
```

Intellij Idea log:

```
2014-01-28 10:16:55,926 [129482004]   INFO - or.jabber.impl.JabberTransport - Jabber  connected 
2014-01-28 10:16:55,926 [129482004]   INFO - or.jabber.impl.JabberTransport - Jabber connected 
2014-01-28 10:17:00,990 [129487068]   INFO - r.jabber.impl.JabberFacadeImpl - No  response from the server. 
No response from the server.: 
at     org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(SASLAuthenticatio    n.java:302)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:209)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:433)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:396)
at jetbrains.communicator.jabber.impl.JabberFacadeImpl._createConnection(JabberFacadeImpl.java:164)
at jetbrains.communicator.jabber.impl.JabberFacadeImpl.connect(JabberFacadeImpl.java:121)
at jetbrains.communicator.jabber.register.RegistrationForm.doLogin(RegistrationForm.java:209)
at jetbrains.communicator.jabber.register.RegistrationForm.access$1100(RegistrationForm.java:41)
at jetbrains.communicator.jabber.register.RegistrationForm$3.run(RegistrationForm.java:190)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
```

Comment: Same issue (although haven't been able to find the intellij log) - but same log on ejabberd side, and same message in IntelliJ client. I can connect fine with Adium, I should note. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I have not. Switched to another chat program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just posted this to Intellij support and according to the techs, this plugin is no longer supported. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74121

Inconvenient as it sounds, we switched to using an external chat solution.